# Find all numbers $x$ satisfying $x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod A$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given any two numbers $M,N \in \{1,2,\ldots,10^{18}\}$, find all numbers $x$ lying between $M$ and $N$ satisfying
$$x^3\equiv1  \pmod A,$$
where $A$ can be any number.

I know the case when A is even. I want to calculate when A is odd.

Comment: $$x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$$

Clearly, $x\equiv1\pmod A$ is a solution 

Now $x^2+x+1=2\dfrac{x(x+1)}2+1\equiv1\pmod2$ i.e., odd hence there will be no other solution if $A$ even


If $A$ is odd $x^2+x+1\equiv0\pmod A\iff(2x+1)^2\equiv-3$

If $A=\prod p_i^{r_i}$ where $p_i$s are distinct primes 


Solve for each $(2x+1)^2\equiv-3\pmod{p_i^{r_i}}$

Comment: Could you please elaborate for the case when A is odd, by giving some example ?

Comment: This question is an attempt to cheat in a programming competition http://www.codechef.com/TCFS15P/ . "Learner" has posted four questions here today from the same competition.